# Remove row from table with fadeOut effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadeout

I have a table that has some rows,each row has a background.
There is a button that remove specified row with jQuery fadeOut, but during the operation the design doesn't good.cells background will be white.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        $("#row").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnKXP/) describes my problem better.

Comment: You already got the fadeout effect? What do you exactly need?

Comment: Please not that calls background will be white color and my background for rows broken

Comment: with this fadeOut effect you can't avoid because it sets opacity in backhand, use $("#row").remove() or $("#row").hide() to avoid this issue

Comment: You can always set the fadeOut effect with a small duration. Like fadeOut("fast") or fadeOut("100")

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The below code will achieve a shrinking row and then hide it without turning the background white

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        $("#row td").animate({'line-height':0},1000).hide(1);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wnKXP/3/)

Animating line height doesnt go all that smoothly with webkit however.

You can also animate the `hide()` function by setting its parameter to the time taken to hide

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        $("#row").hide(1000);
    });
});
```

That however also suffers from the "white background problem" since it animates the opacity.

Adapting from http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/animating-table-rows-with-jquery.html/ gives a nice shrinking without white space in at least Chrome and Firefox

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnKXP/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn").click(function () {
        $('#row')
            .children('td, th')
            .animate({
            padding: 0
        })
            .wrapInner('<div />')
            .children()
            .slideUp(function () {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: included another solution

Comment: This solution is very tricky but worked good.Thank you for your effort

Answer (score 17):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        $("#row").fadeTo("slow",0.7, function(){
            $(this).remove();
        })
    });
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wnKXP/4/

you can set opacity in "0.7"

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You are just hiding the row and not removing it completely. To remove the row completely from the table and also using fadeout effect use this code.

```
 $("#row").fadeOut("slow", function() {
             $("#row").remove();
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the same background to your table which you applied for table row then you will not see any background for rows.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".remove").click(function(){
    $(this).parents("tr").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

here is the link for [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rampellisrinu/xaab0k88/)

Comment: Thats nice, but what about different row colours? I think background on tr fade out td and slide up tr before finally remove tr, or would that be too much?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.hide()` in the place of `.fadeOut()` to avoid this issue.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        $("#row").hide();
    });
});
```

here is the updated [jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/wnKXP/1/)